# Dynamic Foreign Keys - How To Implement?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, polymorphic-associations

I have 4 tables (appointed, class, elected, status) that I want to cross reference into a single table's (members) column. The values of the of 4 tables are time sensitive based off a history table (members_history). The desired result is that the query should output all members and the current appointed position or current elected position, class, and status within the members row and include additional information obtained from the foreign rows.

So instead of just returning:

id, username, password, salt, name_first, name_last, date_join & date_leave;

The query would return

id, username, password, salt, `name_prefix`, name_first, name_last, `hours_extra`, date_join, date_leave, `appointed`, `class`, `elected` & `status`;

Wherever an added column does not have a current value in history it's result should be NULL.

Now I think I can do this with sub-querys, but have been so far banging my head against the keyboard. I'll take another swing at it later, but until then, anyone else willing to give it a shot, or attempt to point me in the right direction?

The structure of my SQL (no pun intended) tables is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
 `id` mediumint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Members Unique Id',
 `username` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mebers Username',
 `password` varchar(64) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members Password Hash',
 `salt` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members Password Salt',
 `name_first` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members First Name',
 `name_last` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members Last Name',
 `date_join` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members Join Date',
 `date_leave` date default NULL COMMENT 'Members Resgination Date (If Applicable)',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Members id in this table = mid in other tables';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members:apointed` (
 `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Unique value',
 `name_prefix` varchar(8) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Prefix Added to Members Name',
 `hours_extra` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hours Given as Bonus for Holding this Position.',
 `position` varchar(40) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Posisiton',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Undefined within the SOP or By-Laws.';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members:class` (
 `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Unique Id',
 `class` varchar(8) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique Value',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `value` (`class`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Article I, Section 1 Subsection B: Classes of Membership';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members:elected` (
 `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Unique value',
 `name_prefix` varchar(8) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Prefix Added to Members Name',
 `hours_extra` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hours Given as Bonus for Holding this Position.',
 `position` varchar(40) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Posisiton',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Article II';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members:status` (
 `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Bit''s Place',
 `status` varchar(16) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Categorie''s Name',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Article I, Section 1, Subsection A: Categories of Membership';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members_history` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Unique Id',
 `mid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members Unique Id.',
 `table` enum('class','elected','appointed','status') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of Table that was Edited.',
 `value` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
 `start` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Value''s Effect Date',
 `end` date default NULL COMMENT 'Value''s Expiration Date',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Member History';
```

members_history.mid is a FK for id in the members table, not every member will have history on them (but eventually they all will, as every member will have to have a class and status). `members_history.value` is a FK for `members:{members_history.table}.id`;

```
INSERT INTO `members`
(`id`, `username`, `password`, `salt`, `name_first`, `name_last`, `date_join`, `date_join`) VALUES
(   1,   'Dygear',MD5('pass'), 's417',       'Mark',    'Tomlin',      DATE(), NULL),
(   2,  'uberusr',MD5('p455'), '235f',     'Howard',    'Singer',      DATE(), NULL),
(   3,'kingchief',MD5('leet'), '32fs','Christopher',   'Buckham',      DATE(), NULL);

INSERT INTO `members:apointed`
(`id`, `name_prefix`, `hours_extra`, `posisiton`) VALUES
(   1,            '',          0.00, 'Crew Chief'),
(   2,            '',         20.00, 'Engineer'),
(   3,         'Lt.',         40.00, 'Lieutenant'),
(   4,       'Capt.',         60.00, 'Captin'),
(   5,      'Chief.',         80.00, '3rd Assistant Chief of Operation');

INSERT INTO `members:class`
(`id`, `class`) VALUES
(   1, 'Class I'),
(   2, 'Class II');

INSERT INTO `members:elected`
(`id`, `name_prefix`, `hours_extra`, `posisiton`) VALUES
(   1,            '',         40.00, 'Trustee'),
(   2,            '',         40.00, 'Chairman of the Board'),
(   3,       'Prez.',         40.00, 'President'),
(   4,      'VPrez.',         40.00, 'Vice-President'),
(   5,            '',         40.00, 'Recording Secretary'),
(   6,            '',         40.00, 'Service Secretary'),
(   7,            '',         40.00, 'Corresponding Secretary'),
(   8,            '',         40.00, 'Financial Secretary Treasuer'),
(   9,            '',         40.00, 'Assistant Financial Secretary Treasuer'),
(  10,      'Chief.',         80.00, 'Chief of Operations'),
(  11,      'Chief.',         80.00, 'First Deputy Chief of Operations'),
(  12,      'Chief.',         80.00, 'Second Deputy Chief of Operation');

INSERT INTO `members:status`
(`id`, `status`) VALUES
(   1, 'Active'),
(   2, 'Inactive'),
(   3, 'Student'),
(   4, 'Probationary'),
(   5, 'Lifetime'),
(   6, 'Cadet'),
(   7, 'Honorary'),
(   8, 'Medical'),
(   9, 'Military'),
(  10, 'Resigned'),
(  11, 'Disvowed');


INSERT INTO `members_history`
(`id`, `mid`,    `table`, `value`, `start`, `end`) VALUES
(NULL,     1, 'apointed',       3,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     1,    'class',       1,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     1,   'status',       1,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     2,  'elected',       4,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     2,    'class',       1,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     2,   'status',       1,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     3, 'apointed',      10,  DATE(), '2010-05-01'),
(NULL,     3,    'class',       1,  DATE(), NULL),
(NULL,     3,   'status',       1,  DATE(), NULL);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using a design called **polymorphic associations** and it's frequently done wrong.  The way to make it work is to create another table, say `members:abstract`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members:abstract` (
 `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `type` enum('class','elected','appointed','status') NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (`id`, `type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

This table serves as the parent table for all of your members attributes tables.  Each of these tables changes its primary key to *not* generate id values automatically, but instead reference the primary key of `members:abstract`.  I'll show just `members:appointed` but the others would be similar.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members:appointed` (
 `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- not auto_increment
 `name_prefix` varchar(8) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Prefix Added to Members Name',
 `hours_extra` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hours Given as Bonus for Holding this Position.',
 `position` varchar(40) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Posisiton',
 FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `members:abstract` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Undefined within the SOP or By-Laws.';
```

You can make this table gain auto-generated values automatically with a trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_appointed//
CREATE TRIGGER ins_appointed BEFORE INSERT ON `members:appointed`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `members:abstract` (`type`) VALUES ('appointed');
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Do the same for each of the other attribute tables.

Note that the id values are now unique across all your attribute tables.

Next you make `members:abstract` the target for a foreign key in `members_history`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members_history` (
 `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Unique Id',
 `mid` INT unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Members Unique Id.',
 `value` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `table` enum('class','elected','appointed','status') NOT NULL,
 `start` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Value''s Effect Date',
 `end` date default NULL COMMENT 'Value''s Expiration Date',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`mid`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (`value`, `table`) REFERENCES `members:abstract` (`id`, `type`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Member History';
```

Notice that this table defines a foreign key so that you *can't* reference an id of the wrong type of attribute in `members:abstract`.

Now you can rely on **referential integrity** and **consistency** which is impossible when you try to implement polymorphic associations without the common parent of all the referenced attribute tables.

Here's the query that returns the result you described (tested on MySQL 5.1.40):

```
SELECT m.username,
  m.password, m.salt, m.name_first, m.name_last,
  MAX(a.name_prefix) AS name_prefix,
  COALESCE(MAX(a.hours_extra), MAX(e.hours_extra)) AS hours_extra,
  MAX(m.date_join) AS date_join,
  MAX(m.date_leave) AS date_leave,
  MAX(a.position) AS appointed,
  MAX(c.class) AS class,
  MAX(e.position) AS elected,
  MAX(s.status) AS status
FROM `members` m 
JOIN `members_history` h ON (h.mid = m.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `members:appointed` a ON (h.table = 'appointed' AND h.value = a.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `members:class` c ON (h.table = 'class' AND h.value = c.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `members:elected` e ON (h.table = 'elected' AND h.value = e.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `members:status` s ON (h.table = 'status' AND h.value = s.id)
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Comment: Outstanding answer Bill, thank you very much. I've learned alot from that.

Comment: Apparently the 'trigger' is not within my power on the production server that I use. Go figure huh.

Comment: The trigger is pretty simple, only two statements long.  You can do something equivalent in your application code each time you insert to one of your tables.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out afterwards. You know, I really did not appreciate the quality of this until just now. Really you did a FANTASTIC job on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: For no apparent reason after making each table in the order of `members:abstract`, `members:appointed`, `members:class`, `members:elected`, `members:status` and then when it gets to making `members_history` it fails with this error: `#1005 - Can't create table './wlvacc_ems/members_history.frm' (errno: 150)`.

Comment: I fixed the last error by removing these lines from the table query:

    FOREIGN KEY (`mid`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`value`, `table`) REFERENCES `members:abstract` (`id`, `type`) ON DELETE CASCADE

All data is now inputted.

However the query you have is giving me an issue:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'a.position' in 'field list'`

Comment: Note that foreign key column(s) must be *exactly* the same type as the primary key column(s) they reference.  INT is not the same as INT UNSIGNED, for instance.  BIGINT is not the same as INT.  And so on.

Comment: Regarding the error about `a.position`, I notice you have quite a few misspellings in your table names.  You should be careful and double-check all your table names and column names if you are prone to typos or misspellings.

Comment: By my testing, when you insert data into members:appointed (or the other sub tables) the LAST_INSERT_ID will always be zero since the id is generated in the trigger function [that value does not persist outside the scope of the trigger]. This could be problematic if you need to get the id after the insert. My current work around is to leave the id column on members:appointed to auto_increment, but add a second column ma_id which is set in the trigger to the members:abstract autokey value. Any feedback on a more elegant solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

all you need is a left outer join for each of the history types and whatever logic you need to pick the "current" row.

your table structure doesn't quite make enough sense to me to put together a sample for you. maybe if you provide ONE sample member and a couple of rows of history for ONE attribute, i can help you out.

Comment: I've added some detail about possible values to the original post.